# Is it better to capture Coded UI for replay on Firefox, by using an older (non-latest) IE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I'm looking to capture some Coded UI using C#, in order to playback in Firefox.

Captures, of course, need to be taken in Internet Explorer.

Right now, I have the latest version (version 10). I am hearing that this can cause issues, with, for example, Radio buttons.

Is it better to capture, with say, IE8 for example? If so, I'm thinking playback will be more effective from a couple of exceptions I'm getting, specifically to do with 'hidden' elements.

Often, issues are attributed to Microsoft Security Update KB2870699.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, Microsoft introduced Selenium components for Coded UI testing [in VS 2013, perhaps in 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx). The [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835758.aspx) for test recording are IE9 or IE10 (or greater?) for VS 2013 per MSDN, so you probably cannot even record in IE8 - but your mileage may vary.

The big issue you may run into with record and playback is if the application you are targeting renders differently for different browsers, for example based on User-Agent. Because the record-and-playback still uses the same Coded UI API under the surface, if for example and ID of a control or a hierarchy is different, or a `<span>` renders as a `<div>` in a different browser, you may need to adjust the test after it is recorded.

You'll only truly know by running the test cross-browser and inspecting the reason for the failure. The recording creates a designer-file of Properties, etc., which you can refactor from `UIMap.Designer.cs` to `UIMap.cs` and adjust as necessary. Remove the `GeneratedCodeAttribute` from the method that you bring over for best practice.

You might find a healthy mix of recorded and adjusted Coded UI tests, or you may opt for direct access to APIs of another framework such as Selenium directly. In summary - recorded tests are quick to generate, but are brittle to changes in rendering. Recording in one browser *should* not affect its ability to playback and pass; otherwise other issues may be at play.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. The primary reason I ask is i have one particular issue, for which the answer is unclear when doing google-searhces for the solution - in short - Radio buttons give an exception, even when playing back in IE (really, I want to playback on Firefox). Though the buttons themselves 'actuate' and correctly indicate actuation. I am hearing a Microsoft security patch scuffed things up a bit in the exception I am getting, but this was for IE9 and above.....so think I will try an earlier version, if VS2013 permits thus.